# Which xml technology to extract fields from an xml file should I use

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax, jaxp

I work with Java. I have a bunch of long XML files. I have to filter the documents by several fields, then I have to extract other fields and then create an java object based on these fields. How should I do this? SAX, JDOM, XSLT, XPATH, JAXP etc.? Sorry I'm not familiar with XML technologies. Can you give me a general architecture for my use case?

Comment: checkout xStream library. It was provided by CodeHause but now it is available on github.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about XML Parsing, and you also in the Java platform. It's looking pretty cool.

You can able to parse the XML stuffs using Java XML Parsers. There are many XML Parsers are available. You might going to use Java Dom Parser, JDOM Parser, SAX parser, StAX Parser or JAXP.

I prefered JAXP is powerful. It's speciallity comparing with DOM parsers. It load the part of the document when it needs.

Better you follow this site to understand the concepts. 
[Java XML Parsers - Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_xml_parsers.htm)